# Get Site Classification via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

For internal audit /validation do I need to load all sites in my tenant where the [classification](https://medium.com/@TCEastham/site-classification-in-office365-397c76a92c4a) of the site is set to "Internal Only" (custom classification created for our tenant).

It seems like that I cannot retrieve the classification using the standard PowerShell module [Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell/16.0.21109.12000) - the object returned by `Get-SPOSite` simply does not provided a property `Classification`.

The only way I have found is using [PnP.PowerShell](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PnP.PowerShell/1.4.12-nightly), see Microsoft documentation [Programmatically read the classification of a site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-site-classification#programmatically-read-the-classification-of-a-site):

```
Connect-PnPOnline "https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[modernsite]" -Credentials [credentials]

$site = Get-PnPSite
$classificationValue = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $site -Property Classification
Write-Host $classificationValue
```

But the problem with the PnP.PowerShell based approach is the fact that I need be be an admin /owner of that site in order to load the site-object. I case I am not an admin /owner is the following error raised when executing `Get-PnPSite`:

```
Get-PnPSite : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Question is now if I could retrieve the classification of all sites in my tenant without being a site-collection administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site collection adiminstator is necessary to retrieve the Classification property.

As a tenant admin, you could add yourself as a site collection admin through powershell. After retrieving the information, just remove Admin account from site colletion administrators.

Like the below:

```
$site="https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[modernsite]"
$admin="admin@tenant.com"
#Add Admin account as an additional site collection adminstrator
Set-PnPTenantSite  $site -Owners $admin

Connect-PnPOnline $site -Credentials [credentials]

$site = Get-PnPSite
$classificationValue = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $site -Property Classification
Write-Host $classificationValue

#Remove Admin account from site colletion administrators
Remove-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin -Owners $admin
```

Comment: I am configured as "Global Administrator" but I can only get the classification if I am the "Site Administrator" of the given site.

Comment: Global Administrator dees not have auto acess to all site collection.As I said, You can add yourself as site adminstrator.

Answer (score 0):

You really need that SharePoint admin role for this to work... There is no way around it.

Comment: I am configured as "Global Administrator" but I can only get the classification if I am the "Site Administrator" of the given site.